# Read data from a txt file and display it in a web form in Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, webforms

How would I go about reading data from a txt file (the file is uploaded with web form) and then displaying the data on the form itself? I know how to do it with StreamReader in a desktop application but am having trouble with the web version. Users can search for a file number and the data for that number would be displayed.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/1356.html)

Comment: If you know how to read the data, then you just need to decide how to display it. Once it is loaded into memory, you can display it however best fits your business needs.